# Get all table columns from subquery result for each subquery result row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below query which is getting list of all permissions which are disabled for particular userId From RolesPermissions table,

```
SELECT PermissionId
FROM RolesPermissions
WHERE HasPermission = 0
    AND RoleId IN (
        SELECT RoleId
        FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
        WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
        )
GROUP BY PermissionId
HAVING Count(PermissionId) = (
        SELECT count(RoleId)
        FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
        WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
        )
```

Above query returns 128 rows, Now I need all RoleId against each permissionId which is return by above query from  RolesPermissions table

```
SELECT B.PermissionId
    ,A.RoleId
FROM RolesPermissions A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PermissionId
    FROM RolesPermissions
    WHERE HasPermission = 0 --Get all permissions for user(Duplicates entries)
        AND RoleId IN (
            SELECT RoleId
            FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
            WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
            )
    GROUP BY PermissionId
    HAVING Count(PermissionId) = (
            SELECT count(RoleId)
            FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
            WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
            )
    ) AS B ON A.PermissionId = B.PermissionId
```

Comment: Try using HasPermission=0 in outside query also

Comment: thanks for ur comment @superB ,Its returning 256 rows after puting HasPermision=0 outside query , I am expecting 128 rows

Comment: If duplicate results are coming, try using Distinct or groupby

Comment: Why are you not fetching RoleID in InnerQuery only ?

Comment: Select distinct  B.PermissionId,A.RoleId from RolesPermissions A
INNER  JOIN   has result of 256 rows and 
where  HasPermission=0      
group by B.PermissionId has error stating 
Column 'RolesPermissions.RoleId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I can't understand you query. Why you just can't  do `SELECT PermissionId, RoleID` in first query with `group by` by this two columns?

Comment: if I try to get RoleId in InnerQuery like
Select PermissionId,RoleId from RolesPermissions where HasPermission=0  
I m getting this error Column 'RolesPermissions.RoleId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @superB thats what I talking about above

Comment: @Evgeny Yeah you are right, that's what I was talking about in my earlier comment also.

Comment: @superB I am sorry but its returning zero records :(

Comment: @Roshan Have you tried my answer, it wont return 0 record.

Comment: Yes @superB with your answer also it is returning zero record

Comment: I dont know what is your problem now, you can check other query also. but output would be same.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is more than 1 role for each permission right?  So you are expecting more than 128 results for your second query?

Comment: Yes  @Quantumplate you are right , I should have more than 128 rows,I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT B.PermissionId
    ,A.RoleId
FROM RolesPermissions A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PermissionId
    FROM RolesPermissions
    WHERE HasPermission = 0 --Get all permissions for user(Duplicates entries)
        AND RoleId IN (
            SELECT RoleId
            FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
            WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
            )
    GROUP BY PermissionId
    HAVING Count(PermissionId) = (
            SELECT count(RoleId)
            FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
            WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
            )
    ) AS B ON A.PermissionId = B.PermissionId Where HasPermission = 0
          AND A.RoleId IN (
            SELECT RoleId
            FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
            WHERE UserId = '3ee38aa9-0e1a-4805-9506-aa47aa38a79c'
            )
    group by B.PermissionId,A.RoleId
```

Comment: I am afraid , I tried both first return zero and second returns 256 rows.

Comment: tried with 2nd one it is still returning 256 rows @superB